# Is minmax equivalent to maxmin?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

More precisely, problem $1$ is as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
&\max_{1{\le}i{\le}N}\min_{[\gamma_m^i]}\left[\lambda_i - \sum_{m=1}^M\phi_m\gamma_m^iF_m^i\right] \\
&\mbox{subject to} \sum_{i=1}^N\gamma_m^i = 1,\mbox{ for all }m=1,\cdots,M \\
&\gamma_m^i \ge 0,\mbox{ for all }i=1,\cdots,N\mbox{ and }m.
\end{eqnarray}

More precisely, Problem $2$ is as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
&\min_{[\gamma_m^i]}\max_{1{\le}i{\le}N}\left[\lambda_i - \sum_{m=1}^M\phi_m\gamma_m^iF_m^i\right] \\
&\mbox{subject to} \sum_{i=1}^N\gamma_m^i = 1,\mbox{ for all }m=1,\cdots,M \\
&\gamma_m^i \ge 0,\mbox{ for all }i=1,\cdots,N\mbox{ and }m.
\end{eqnarray}

where $\boldsymbol{\phi}$ is a probability vector in $\textbf{P}_M$, $F_m^i{\in}\Re, \forall{i}, \forall{m}$. According to Sion's maxmin theorem, are these two problems equivalent? I would appreciate if I would get some hints.

Comment: In general, the two problems are _not_ equivalent. See more details in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840299/is-minimax-equals-to-maximin/840368#840368).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can solve Problem $2$ using matlab fminimax function. Is there any way to solve Problem $1$ using matlab function? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Problem 1 is just $N$ separate solves using a solver of your choice.